# ESX Unix guest & AnywhereUSB

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, centos5, usb

We got a Nagios (FAN) VM within an ESXi little cluster (4 servers).
I have to configure SMS alerts with Nagios, so I have to plug a phone via usb.

Problem : I want my usb to be seen even if my VM switches of ESX (because a physical server is down, or something else).

So I think I must use our AnywhereUSB, USB over IP.

Question is : do a CentOS VM will see our usb correctly ? Because i can't find unix drivers for the AnywhereUSB. Is it needed ?

EDIT : I just plugged the phone on a physical ESXi. And share it with the VM I wanted. I didn't look further.

(I edited this post, also because he's blocking me for asking question on this SE forum. Even if on other SE forum i'm fine ... So I apologize for this bad post.)

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to ask...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess at what you're trying to do:

> 1. You have a Virtual Machine running Nagios.
> 2. You want to connect a cellular device to the VM (via USB) to send SMS alerts.

ESXi can do [USB pass-through](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.vmadmin.doc_41/vsp_vm_guide/configuring_virtual_machines/c_configuring_usb_passthrough_devices.html), so yes: you can connect your SMS-sending-device to your VM.
There is no need to do "USB over IP" or any other terrible hackery.

Whether drivers would be required or not is something we can't tell you.
The device will appear as a USB-connected peripheral. Your VM would need to treat it like it would any other USB-connected peripheral. (This means either some kind of OS driver, or software using the HID library or similar to talk directly to the device.)

Comment: USB pass-through is what i need :) Thanks. But problem is : I lost Vmotion feature, by using this. but it seems there is no solution

Comment: He mentions an ESXi cluster with 4 servers. How can you do USB passthrough with multiple hosts ? I guess that's why he is asking a question about usb-over-ip